# Issues with mousePressed in p5js

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I am trying to build a simple app that plays a song when you press/click on the screen. Once you press/click a ripple effect will happen as well making a visual aspect to it.

The ripple should happen every time you press/click but in my code (restarts every time you click), you press and the ripple happens, but doesn't keep looping. I know the answer is on the tip of my tongue but I can't figure it out. Also, when my sketch loads, a purple box appears and I'm not sure why.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="resources\p5.js"></script>
    <script src="resources\p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="resources\p5.sound.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js\app.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css\style.css">
    <title>Breathe</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>


* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


let outerDiam = 0;
let cnv;
let drawThings;

function centerCanvas() {
  var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
  var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
  cnv.position(x, y);
}

function setup() { 
  cnv = createCanvas(600, 600);
  centerCanvas();
  background(255, 0, 255);
} 

function windowResized() {
  centerCanvas();
}

function draw() { 
  if (drawThings) {
      background(255);
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        let diam = outerDiam - 30 * i;    
        if (diam > 0){

          let fade = map(diam, 0, width, 0, 255);
            stroke(fade);
            noFill();
            ellipse(300, 300, diam);
    }


        outerDiam = outerDiam + 2;
    } 
    }
  }

function mousePressed() {
  drawThings = !drawThings;
}
```

Comment: `outerDiam` is never reset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your mousePressed function, you never actually reset the animation, you just toggle playing.

```js
function mousePressed() {
  drawThings = !drawThings;
}
```

When it does start playing again when you click, the animation just continues where it left off.

Instead of turning drawing off when you click, reset `outerDiam` to 0.
So this:

```
function draw() { 
  if (drawThings) {
    [...]
  }

function mousePressed() {
  drawThings = !drawThings;
}
```

becomes this:

```
function draw() { 
  [...]
}

function mousePressed() {
  outerDiam = 0;
}
```

---

Also the "purple box" is created due to the background being set to purple at the beginning:

```
function setup() { 
  [...]
  background(255, 0, 255); //red is 255, green is 0 and blue is 255 so it appears purple
}
```

This is overwritten when you start drawing by the background function in draw() but in the code you've given background stays this color until you click as `drawThings` wasn't defined to begin with and only became `true` when you first clicked.

If you make the changes I have suggested above then this background in setup() will immediately be drawn over so you won't see a purple background at all. (I would recommend removing this first background function which is in the setup function.)

Comment: Nice touch explaining the background thing.

Comment: ahhh thank you so much! Yes this makes total sense. Going to try this soon.

Comment: everything worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I took a 3.5 month break from coding and I am trying to get back into it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your code, now the animation plays every time you press the mouse:

```
"use strict";

let outerDiam = 0;
let cnv;
let drawThings;

function centerCanvas() {
  var x = (windowWidth - width) / 2;
  var y = (windowHeight - height) / 2;
  cnv.position(x, y);
}

function setup() {
  cnv = createCanvas(600, 600);
  centerCanvas();
  background(255, 0, 255);
}

function windowResized() {
  centerCanvas();
}

function draw() {
  //if (drawThings) {
  background(255);
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    let diam = outerDiam - 30 * i;
    if (diam > 0) {

      let fade = map(diam, 0, width, 0, 255);
      stroke(fade);
      noFill();
      ellipse(300, 300, diam);
    }


    outerDiam = outerDiam + 2;
  }
  //}
}

function mousePressed() {
  drawThings = !drawThings;
  outerDiam = 0;
}
```